# How do you include JavaScript in MasterPage?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am building an ASP.NET Webform application with C# in VS 2012, .NET framework 4.5

I have a MasterPage in root of application, JavaScript files are in folder named js.

Here is the problem: **If page are in root folder** then everything is **working fine** (css+js), if I put any **pages in subfolder** then css is worked but those JavaScripts are **not working** at all, obviously the reference path is wrong.

So the Css reference path is fine, but for the script no matter what I used they all are not worked (js/script.js or ~/js/script.js or /js/script.js or ../ ResolveUrl, ResolClientveUrl ... or all of method in this http://yobriefca.se/blog/2010/10/19/%3C-head-%3Eache-including-javascript-in-asp-dot-net-master-pages/ ) they all refer to root/SUB-FOLDER/**js/script.js** instead of root/**js/script.js**

in root: a single MasterPage, Default.aspx, test.aspx, js folder, css folder and Pages folder. Default and test pages are working file, but all pages in Pages folder is not display .js SO OBLIVIOUSLY the path is wrong whenever pages is not in root

In my master page:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />

<%-- tried these and lot more but NOT workkkkkkkkkkk --%>

<%--<script src="~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="~/js/script.js" ></script>--%>

<%--<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>' ></script>
<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/script.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

<%--<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/script.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

the script.js is somthing like:

```
....
    $.include('js/superfish.js')
$.include('js/FF-cash.js')
$.include('js/tms-0.4.x.js')
$.include('js/uCarausel.js')
$.include('js/jquery.easing.1.3.js')
$.include('js/jquery.tools.min.js')
$.include('js/jquery.jqtransform.js')
$.include('js/jquery.quicksand.js')
$.include('js/jquery.snippet.min.js')
$.include('js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js')
$.include('js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js')
$.include('js/jquery.cookie.js')
$(function(){
    if($('.tweet').length)$.include('js/jquery.tweet.js');
    if($('.lightbox-image').length)$.include('js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js');
    if($('#contact-form').length||$('#contact-form2').length)$.include('js/forms.js');
    if($('.kwicks').length)$.include('js/kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js');
    if($('#counter').length)$.include('js/jquery.countdown.js');
    if($('.fixedtip').length||$('.clicktip').length||$('.normaltip').length)$.include('js/jquery.atooltip.pack.js')
// Slider
    $('.main-slider')._TMS({
.....
```

ERROR in developer tool (Console) of web browser:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/tms-0.4.x.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/uCarausel.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery.jqtransform.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery.quicksand.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery.snippet.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/FF-cash.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/superfish.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery.tools.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ApplicationRoot/Pages/js/jquery.cookie.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_TMS' script.js:22
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

Comment: You should remove `~/`. since script isn't ASP.NET control, it's added to final html as it is, and browser can't recognize `~/`.

Comment: @Givi not worked, I tried all method /js, ../js, ~/js or js then same in ResolveUrl and ResolClientveUrl

Comment: Remove server side comment tag. `<%-- --%>`

Comment: @Givi Removed <%-- --%> and all pages included pages in root folder is not worked

Comment: Can you show structure of your server? and expand structure of master page?

Comment: @Givi: There is nothing now, in root: a single MasterPage, Default.aspx, test.aspx, js folder, css folder and Pages folder. Default and test pages are working file, but all pages in Pages folder is not display .js SO OBLIVIOUSLY the path is wrong whenever pages is not in root

Comment: A very helpful article on all sorts of path definitions in ASP.NET http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## HTML

You typically don't want any scripts in the `<head />` apart from scripts like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) that have feature detection.  It's more of a best practice to move all scripts to the bottom of the page like so:

```html
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/style.css") %>' />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Scripts at bottom of page for faster loading. -->

    <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>'></script>
    <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/script.js") %>'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

## SCRIPT.JS

Referencing the other script files in **script.js** will require the `/` to be appened to 'js/` like so:

```js
$.include('/js/superfish.js');
$.include('/js/FF-cash.js');
$.include('/js/tms-0.4.x.js');
$.include('/js/uCarausel.js');
$.include('/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');
$.include('/js/jquery.tools.min.js');
$.include('/js/jquery.jqtransform.js');
$.include('/js/jquery.quicksand.js');
$.include('/js/jquery.snippet.min.js');
$.include('/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js');
$.include('/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js');
$.include('/js/jquery.cookie.js');

if($('.tweet').length)
    $.include('/js/jquery.tweet.js');

if($('.lightbox-image').length)
    $.include('/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js');

if($('#contact-form').length || $('#contact-form2').length)
    $.include('/js/forms.js');

if($('.kwicks').length)
    $.include('/js/kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js');

if($('#counter').length)
    $.include('/js/jquery.countdown.js');

if($('.fixedtip').length || $('.clicktip').length || $('.normaltip').length)
    $.include('/js/jquery.atooltip.pack.js');

// Slider
$('.main-slider')._TMS({
```

---

## MISC

*Don't forget to clear your cache or work in private browsing while testing all of this!*

Comment: ok so I edit script.js file as you suggeted (basically removed /js), I still get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:52403/Pages/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js So obviously it is always point to SUBFOLDER then js/script.js rather than directly point to js/script.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:52403/Pages/js/script.js

Comment: Master page like you showed, <script> at bottom right above </body> tag, remember pages in root folder (same as masterpage) is worked fine

Comment: So, is the js folder on the same folder level as the MasterPage?

Comment: in root: a single MasterPage, Default.aspx, test.aspx, js folder, css folder and Pages folder. Default and test pages are working file, but all pages in Pages folder is not display .js SO OBLIVIOUSLY the path is wrong whenever pages is not in root

Comment: the missing (not found) JS file are those files in script.js file

Comment: same problem, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:52403/IntroPages/js/superfish.js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43367/discussion-between-ronaldinhostate-and-code-maverick)

Comment: Hey I got problem again with asp and jquery, something similar to this can you please help via teamviewer?

Answer (score 4):

You can include a .js file either between the head tags , contentplaceholder tags or inside the body tags. This will in all cases be reflected in your other pages that include this masterpage. All you need to focus on is the way that the path is created.

The code below adds a jquery file to a masterpage in the head section of the masterpage.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
```

```
<title></title>

<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
<script>

</script>
```

**Relative vs Absolute URL's**

By using ../ and ~/ before the url path , you are creating a relative URL. The paths of relative URL's is affected when you change the folder level of either the file that you are referring to or the file which contains the link.

../ symbol make one step out of the folder containing the link. make sure you have enough '../' to refer to the correct file.

~/ symbol creates a path that starts at the root of your project.

To create an absolute URL ,Just drag the file you intend to include in the page from solution explorer in Visual Studio to the page.

For more about the difference between absolute and relative URL's check 
[Difference between Relative path and absolute path in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing **~/** with **../**.  One of my projects was doing the same thing and that fixed it.

Also, make absolutely certain that even on the server (and not just in the project), the JS folder is directly below the root.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `~` prefix, before file location. (like this: `~/projects/files/web/admin` )

Answer (score 0):

If you want the js to load on every page, including relative paths, then add it just under the modernizr entry:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/my.js") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```