# Difference between Relative path and absolute path in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have small clarifications,

As of my knowledge these are the relative and absolute paths,

```
Completely relative: <img src="kitten.png"/>   
Absolute in all respects: <img src="http://www.foo.com/images/kitten.png">
```

What is the difference between Relative path and absolute path?

Is there any performance issues occur for using these paths?

Will we get any secure for the sites ?

Is there any way of converting absolute path to relative

Comment: There is a very good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> What is the difference between Relative path and absolute path?

One has to be calculated with respect to another URI. The other does not.

> Is there any performance issues occures for using these paths?

Nothing significant.

> We will get any secure for the sites ?

No

> Is there any way to converting absolute path to relative

In *really* simplified terms: Working from left to right, try to match the scheme, hostname, then path segments with the URI you are trying to be relative to. Stop when you have a match.

Comment: When you say nothing significant regarding performance, what if you had a project with 1 million link that were relative using the ./ syntax and 1 million links that were virtual/absolute using the ~/ syntax. and they were called one after another. Would there be a performance drop with one of these methods?

Comment: @EricB — The performance difference would matter when loading the page with the HTML describing the links, not when resolving them. gzip compression at the transport level would probably eliminate the difference. Having 1,000,000 links in a single page would make it a very stupid page to begin with.

Answer (score 67):

The path with reference to root directory is called **absolute**. 
The path with reference to current directory is called **relative**.

Comment: which one is batter/faster relative or absolute ?

Comment: I believe relative path cuz it is not dependent on any location?

Answer (score 35):

Completely relative:

```
<img src="kitten.png"/>
```

this is a relative path indeed.

Absolute in all respects:

```
<img src="http://www.foo.com/images/kitten.png"/>
```

this is a URL, and it can be seen in some way as an absolute path,
but it's not representative for this matter.

The difference between relative and absolute paths is that when using relative paths you take as reference the current working directory while with absolute paths you refer to a certain, well known directory. Relative paths are useful when you make some program that has to use resources from certain folders that can be opened using the working directory as a starting point.

Example of relative paths:

- `image.png`, which is the equivalent to `.\image.png` (in Windows)
  or `./image.png` (anywhere else). 
  The `.` explicitly specifies that you're expressing a path
  relative to the current working directory,
  but this is implied whenever the path *doesn't* begin at a root directory
  (designated with a slash), so you don't have to use it necessarily
  (except in certain contexts where a default directory
  (or a list of directories to search)
  will be applied unless you explicitly specify some directory).
- `..\images\image2.jpg` 
  This way you can access resources from directories one step up the folders tree.  The `..\` means you've exited the current folder,
  entering the directory that contains both the working and `images` folders. 
  Again, use `\` in Windows and `/` anywhere else.

Example of absolute paths:

- `D:\documents\something.doc`
- `E:\music\good_music.mp3`

and so on.

Comment: For windows not difference between - '/' and '\'

Answer (score 10):

**Relative Paths**

A relative path assumes that the file is on the current server.  Using relative paths allows you to construct your site offline and fully test it before uploading it.

For example:

`php/webct/itr/index.php`

.

**Absolute Paths**

An absolute path refers to a file on the Internet using its full URL. Absolute paths tell the browser precisely where to go.

For example:

`http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/php/webct/itr/index.php`

Absolute paths are easier to use and understand.  However, it is not good practice on your own website.  For one thing, using relative paths allows you to construct your site offline and fully test it before uploading it.  If you were to use absolute paths you would have to change your code before uploading it in order to get it to work. This would also be the case if you ever had to move your site or if you changed domain names.

Reference: http://openhighschoolcourses.org/mod/book/tool/print/index.php?id=12503

Comment: Aboslute paths do not refer just to files on the internet. "An absolute path is defined as the specifying the location of a file or directory from the root directory(/). In other words we can say absolute path is a complete path from start of actual filesystem from / directory."

Answer (score 9):

Imagine you have a window open on `http://www.foo.com/bar/page.html`
In all of them (HTML, Javascript and CSS):

```
opened_url = http://www.foo.com/bar/page.html
base_path = http://www.foo.com/bar/
home_path = http://www.foo.com/
/kitten.png = Home_path/kitten.png
kitten.png = Base_path/kitten.png
```

In HTML and Javascript, the base_path is based on the opened window. In big javascript projects you need a `BASEPATH` or `root` variable to store the base_path occasionally. (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368151/define-a-base-url-in-backbone-js-router))

In CSS the opened url is the address of which your .css is stored or loaded, its not the same like javascript with current opened window in this case.

And for being more secure in absolute paths it is recommended to use `//` instead of `http://` for possible future migrations to `https://`. In your own example, use it this way:

```
<img src="//www.foo.com/images/kitten.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy understandable example:

```
// Absolute links:
import TextInput from "src/views/atoms/text-input";
import Button from "src/views/atoms/buttons";

// Relative links:
import TextInput from "../../atoms/text-input";
import Button from "../../atoms/buttons";
```

Answer (score 0):

Going Relative:

- You could download a self-contained directory (maybe a zipped file)
  and open links from an html or xml locally without need to reach the
  server. This increases speed performance significantly,
  specially if you have to deal with a slow network.

Going Absolute:

- You would have to swallow the network speed, but in terms of security
  you    could prevent certain users to see certain files or increase
  network traffic if (and only if...) that is good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will help you in understanding this more simply.

Path differences in Windows

Windows absolute path
C:\Windows\calc.exe

Windows non absolute path (relative path)
calc.exe

In the above example, the absolute path contains the full path to the file and not just the file as seen in the non absolute path. In this example, if you were in a directory that did not contain "calc.exe" you would get an error message. However, when using an absolute path you can be in any directory and the computer would know where to open the "calc.exe" file.

Path differences in Linux

Linux absolute path
/home/users/c/computerhope/public_html/cgi-bin

Linux non absolute path (relative path)
/public_html/cgi-bin

In these example, the absolute path contains the full path to the cgi-bin directory on that computer.
How to find the absolute path of a file in Linux
Since most users do not want to see the full path as their prompt, by default the prompt is relative to their personal directory as shown above. To find the full absolute path of the current directory use the pwd command.

It is a best practice to use relative file paths (if possible).

When using relative file paths, your web pages will not be bound to your current base URL. All links will work on your own computer (localhost) as well as on your current public domain and your future public domains.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the relative version on http://www.foo.com/abc your browser will look at http://www.foo.com/abc/kitten.png for the image and would get 404 - Not found.