# how to include a file which is outside the projectfolder in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, path

I usually include my script files like this:

`<script type='text/javascript' src="app/scripts/my_script.js"></script>` which works fine

as everything lives in the `myproject` folder. But now I have a file that lives outside, two levels above the project folder:

```
bigproject/
    --projectjack/
         --myproject/
    --my_other_script.js
```

I tried including it like this

`<script type='text/javascript' src="full/path/to/my_other_script.js"></script>`

but it didn't find it as it goes through the `myproject` folder. It looked it up here: `myproject/full/path/to/my_other_script.js`

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reference the root of your `bigproject` (assuming that is the root) so prepend a slash like `/full/path/to/my_other_script.js`.

If `bigproject` is not the root, you can try `../../full/path/to/my_other_script.js` but this has the down side of assuming that your project will always be two directories under the `bigproject` which may not always be the case.

You can read up on paths in other places on SO as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21307090/1861459

Answer (score 1):

My .js file is present at drive 'G:\SecuredFILES' but my .html file present at 'G:\SecuredFILES\Study tutorial\java script tutorial' i use the following path which is working good  type="text/javascript" src="G:\SecuredFILES\jquery.js">
Hope so it is enough for your problem