# node.js (express) linking css/js

Tags: node.js, express

I have problem with linking my css/js on my page.
Linking on `localhost:5000/books/1` not working
 but on the page `localhost:5000/books/` working

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

bookRouter.route('/')
            .get(function(req,res){
    res.render('books',{title:"Tytuł", nav:[
                            {
                                Link: "/Books",
                                Text: "Books"
                            },{
                                Link: "/Authors",
                                Text: "Authors"
                            }],
                            books: books
                       });


});

bookRouter.route('/:id')
            .get(function(req,res){

        var id = req.params.id;
      res.render('bookView',{title:"Tytuł", nav:[
                            {
                                Link: "/Books",
                                Text: "Books"
                            },{
                                Link: "/Authors",
                                Text: "Authors"
                            }],
                            book: books[id]
                       });


});

app.use('/books',bookRouter);
```

Route work but not linking css/jss. It looking in http://localhost:5000/books/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Please, post the code that routes `/books/:id`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably addressed the css files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Replace it by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript) if you want to learn more about absolute and relative pathes.

Comment: why href="/books/ I don't have dir book ? Now it looking books/books/lib

Comment: public => css, lib, js

Comment: Yes I have this folder

Comment: where is it? Can you post the path to your `bootstrap.min.css`?

Comment: If you don't start the path with `/`, it is going to be a relative path. It means whatever the url is, it is going to append it to the url. if you start it with `/`, it is going to be appended to your domain, not the url. so it would work for all urls. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript/21306892#21306892).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with yours.
The point is why it looks for  CSS files(or js) from http://localhost:5000/books/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
instead of from
http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

try to add

```
<base href="/">
```

in your html files. Mines worked.