# Adding <link> to <head> Using php

Tags: php, html

I have a page which contains a link tags for stylesheets and scripts for the javascript files, I want to append those scripts in the head section of the page but using the php not using jQuery.

**Testimonial.php**

```
$ex_style = '<link href="'.$_path_.' /css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
$ex_script = '<script src="'.$_path_.' /js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript" />';
// My PHP Code 
...
```

How do I use above `$ex_style` and `$ex_script` using php and append in head of the page?

Lets take it this way.

I have a testimonials script which is installed on a **www.domain-a.com**, 
I want to display testimonials in sidebar on **www.domain-b.com** using php function like

```
include('http://www.domain-a.com/script/testimonial.php');
```

Where `testimonial.php` contains only php code and javascript and css it does not have `<head>` and `<body>` elements.

*Example :  in Wordpress there is a parameter in [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function where we can set it to add script in footer.*

Comment: simply echo `$ex_style` and `$ex_script` in your head, your question not clear to me, whats your problem exactly, if i understand right, just echo those variables.

Comment: I'm having those variables in another page which doesn't contains the header and footer.

I will Update the question again.

Comment: well, so include that file where you want to echo those variables.

Comment: I am not clear with your question. @jiff: have you understood it?

Comment: @RaviHirani he want to echo variable from another file, in this case want to echo style and script link.

Comment: very confused.. but after read your updated question: you **CAN NOT** include a php file from another (external) domain!

Comment: @Maqk: Are you sure both domains are different? I yes then why do you want it include?

Comment: Yes both domains are different. Let me add more bits to the question

Comment: @Maqk: agree with Jiff.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @Maqk: You need to read some tutorial regarding Real Path Vs Absolute Path.  You cannot access browser URL in include function.

Comment: Can we write a function in php and push scripts in head section?

Comment: You can use Ajax or cURL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103204/discussion-between-maqk-and-ravi-hirani).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access Absolute URL in include function.

See the examples below:-

**Relative Paths**

> index.html
>
> /graphics/image.png
>
> /help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html

**Absolute Paths**

> http://www.mysite1.com
>
> http://www.mysite2.com/graphics/image.png
>
> http://www.mysite3.com/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html

The first difference you'll notice between the two different types of links is that absolute paths always include the domain name of the website, including http://www., whereas relative links only point to a file or a file path. When a user clicks a relative link, the browser takes them to that location on the current site. For that reason, you can only use relative links when linking to pages or files within your site, and you must use absolute links if you're linking to a location on another website.

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript) also.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the include method, like with those 2 example files

```
vars.php
 <?php 
  $color = 'green';
  $fruit = 'apple';
 ?>
test.php
<?php echo "A $color $fruit"; // will return A
  include 'vars.php';    
  echo "A $color $fruit";// will return  A green apple 
?>
```

Or read this page: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: This is not the same case.

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution:

```
<head>
<?php
 // use require_once not include
 require_once 'external.php';

 echo $ex_style . $ex_script
?>
</head>
```

Comment: I don't have access to header php file to add. I knew its very simple. Take some time to understand. Let me put the full code in my question for clear understanding.