# Adding MP3 to jquery for background music

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

The basic structure of my jquery slider is as follows:
HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="position:absolute;" class="active" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .active{
        z-index:99;
    }
</style>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

Now, I want to add a MP3 file to it for playing background music which should have following attributes: autoplay on loading = yes, loop= yes, volume = 50

What code should I use for it and where should it be placed? (don’t want to show controls)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
<audio autoplay preload='auto' loop id="myAudio">
  <source src="song name with extension" type="audio/mpeg" >
</audio>
```

For volume :

```
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.volume = 0.5; // default 1 means 100%
```

preload -> The author thinks that the browser should load the entire audio file when the page loads

> Note : For mobile, you have to give click event to load audio/video.

*Remember you should give absolute path at song name or keep that file*

Once try.

It should work.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. :) By 'absolute path', do you mean url of that mp3?

Comment: this means path from root folder. check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)

Comment: or keep that mp3 file in the same folder where your current file

Comment: Well, I understand. I uploaded one mp3 file to my Google drive to get an absolute path for it but the URL doesn't give .mp3 extension. Check:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwx2dCRPVvabQlVUUmlxVFRUUnM    What went wrong?

Comment: ohh, let me give you sample url [here](http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3). What my concern is, if you're doing this on live site, store a sample mp3 file in base path and give that file path to your source src

Comment: Yes, I want to use mp3 on my bogger blog, hence, I desire to store these files on Google drive. Didn't quite understand what you mean by ,base path' and how to give it a source src. Just tell me how to use the audio link I posted above to use in the code you have given. Thanks!

Comment: ok, if you want to access google drive files, then no need to worry about base path, why can't you put your files on dropbox, its alternative, and also provides user friends urls unlike google drive

Comment: Yeah, google drive doesn't provide .mp3 extension for audio and .jpeg for images. Does dropbox provide that?

Comment: Yes, give it a try, you will come to know

Comment: I am sure it will work, if my answer solves your sort of problem, you can upvote it and accept my answer. Thanks. n remember mate, I am here, for further concern. Thanks

Comment: Sure, I would love to upvote. Did lot of research and came to know that cloud services like dropbox or icloud don'y provide this option, only hoisting websites like photobucket or village.photos do. Village.photos is awesome! Posted another question today on stackoverflow. Just check out please!