# one upload directory for two laravel project

Tags: php, upload

two Laravel project are installed under root and `root/superadmin` in my domain. both projects have upload feature. So I want a common upload directory for both.

I tried `public_path('/uploads/')` which points to `public/uploads` for each Laravel. Are they any ways to configure upload image goes to like `public_html/uploads/` and from both projects I can access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your config file to include an absolute path.
In [config/filesystems.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php#L53) set root to the absolute path of your upload folder.

```
...
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => /var/absolute/path/goes/here,
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
...
```

Comment: 'root' => 'public_html/uploads/',
do you mean it for both application ? thanks

Comment: Yup but 'public_html/uploads/' is a relative path. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript