# How do I include other files in PHP?

Tags: php, header, directory, include, footer

I just started creating a website at my home.

Absolutely, I must have these two pages to finish my website rapidly:- `footer.php`, `header.php`.

So I created those pages & put  some contents. Also created an index page as `index.php` inside the `htdocs` folder.

Then I did include the `header` & `footer` pages inside the `index.php` page by using these following codes.

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Undoubtedly, they worked fine without any trouble.

Then I created a directory as `account` inside the `htdocs`.

Now I've a `login.php` page inside the `account` directory (`/account/login.php`).

Repeatedly I used those same codes to include the `header` & `footer` in the login page. But they didn't work! I saw nothing is happening. If I create the `login.php` page inside of the  `htdocs` folder (not in `htdocs/account/`), so it works.

So, how can I include them while the login page is in `account` directory?

Comment: Try <?php include '../header.php'; ?>

You have to go back one folder

Comment: Do you use relative paths in include? e.g. `<?php include '../header.php'; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a file path problem，you can use this code:

```
<?php include '../header.php'  ?>
<?php include '../footer.php'  ?>
```

Load the file of the first level directory。

Answer (score 1):

When creating sub directories and including files it is always simpler to use absolute file paths.

The path with reference to root directory is called **absolute** (https://www.website.com/modules/header.php), you can even remove the domain and just have /modules/header.php. The path with reference to current directory is called **relative** (../images/phone.png). The ../ indicates that the URL points to the directory above the current folder.

Please see answers relating to a similar question here: [difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)

Comment: With regard to PHP and `include()`, absolute path would be any path starting with `/`, denoting the root of file system (or starting with `c:\` - or any other drive letter - on Windows). You wouldn't usually want to include something through HTTP wrapper as the included script would be interpreted by the server and only the result (HTML, JSON etc.) would be returned.

Comment: Yes indeed, hence my comment: 'you can even remove the domain and just have /modules/header.php.'