# Change the background image URL

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to have a function to change the background image URL in a div (see below). It shows `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` in the console when running. Does the new image have to be hosted locally?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script> 
      function changeback() {
        var x = document.getElementById('im').value;    
        document.getElementById('containerH').style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/'+x+')';
      }  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="im" onKeyUp="changeback();" onKeyPress="changeback();"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div id="containerH" style="background-image:url(https://thejasfiles.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/summerholidays-heading.jpg); width:200px; height:400px; margin-left: 12%; margin-top: -2%;">
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be hosted locally, but you have part of a url path hard coded there in the changeback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `'url(img/'+x+')';` value. `img/` is a **relative path** to the current page and therefore it will try to lookup the image **locally** inside the relative 'img' folder.

```html
<html >
<head>
<script> 
function changeback() {
     var x = document.getElementById('im').value;  
           document.getElementById('containerH').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + x + ')';
       
  } 
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="im" onKeyUp="changeback();" onKeyPress="changeback();"></textarea><br>
<div  id="containerH" style="background-image:url(https://thejasfiles.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/summerholidays-heading.jpg); width:200px; height:400px; margin-left: 12%; margin-top: -2%;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See this other post about  [the difference between relative and absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you very much, Richy! Can I please also ask what the "+" sign before and after the var are really used for? Thanks!

Comment: The "+" are used to concatenate values in Javascript. The backgroundImage[1] only accept a string. So in your case, if `x = "https://exemple.com/image.png"` It will become `...backgroundImage = 'url(https://exemple.com/image.png)';`


  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp