# Why does image.src == "file.png" not return true with local files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to switch between two images every time they're clicked.

I've tried creating a script that first gets the image with `var image = document.getElementById(id);` and then checks which image is currently active with `if (image.src == "a.png")` but this never returns true.

When I print it with `console.log(image.src)` the whole source appears:

```
file:///C:/Users...../a.png
```

The idea was to have something like this:

```
var image = document.getElementById(id);
    if (image.src == "a.png") {
      image.src = "b.png";
    }
    else {
      image.src = "a.png";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question. Is `file:///C:/Users...../a.png` equal to `a.png`?

Comment: It should be, but I don't want to use the whole name, since that won't work if I move the folder around

Comment: What about `if(image.src.endsWith('a.png')){` ?

Comment: See my answer for the correct way to use paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's [how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement):

> `HTMLImageElement.src` is a DOMString that [reflects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003819/1048572) the `src` HTML attribute, containing the full URL of the image including base URI.

Notice that this behaviour is not restricted to local files. You can try `image.getAttribute("src") == "a.png"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way:

```
var image = document.getElementById(id);
    if (image.src.includes("a.png")) {
      image.src = image.src.replace("a.png", "b.png");
    }
    else {
      image.src = image.src.replace("b.png", "a.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but I wouldn't use this in production.

Comment: It may be more appropriate to use **endsWith** instead of **includes** as the name of a file is always at the end of the string. It will also avoids  frequently problems with OS file rename. For example a file called "a.png.txt" would match with includes, but not using endsWith

Comment: @RodFerreira endsWith would also match "aa.png", which is also incorrect. Neither *endsWith* nor *includes* are solid options. Correct use of paths is the right way to do this.

Comment: You are absolutely right @KayakinKoder. It would be better to get a substring based on the last slash character index and test it against the file name

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code.

```js
var image = document.getElementById("img");
    if (image.src.indexOf("b.png") > -1) {
      image.src = "b.png";
    }
    else {
      image.src = "a.png";
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `image.src` has the value `file:///C:/Users...../a.png` not just `a.png`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already identified the problem: your `image.src` value is the full file path, but you're only comparing the file name and extension. Instead of `if (image.src == "a.png")` try `if (image.src.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop() == "a.png")`.

Comment: I feel like that's just a complicated workaround of something that should be a bit more simple

Answer (score 0):

On your local computer, what is the path to the image? It is:

`file:///C:/Users/Myntekt/Whatever.../a.png`

as your console.log shows. As your comment noted, you don't want this though, as this won't work on a webserver (or anywhere else that is not your personal computer). The way we typically handle this is by specifying paths as such, notice the leading `/`:

`<img src="/a.png">`

This allows you to put your app on any server, and it will work correctly (read up on [Difference between Relative path and absolute path in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)) On your local computer, you'll then need to run your project on a server. An easy way to do this if you happen to use Webstorm IDE is use their built in server; you can also use something like WAMP, XAMPP, etc.

Comment: I tried that, but with the / the image just doesn't load in the first place and a missing image thing appears in its place

Comment: @Myntekt yes you'll need to run your project on a "server", you can't just open your .html files in your browser like normal. It may take you a few hours to figure out how to do that, but it'll make your life 100% easier. Check out http://www.wampserver.com/en/ It allows you to create an actual Apache server on your computer that you can then run your project on. Another option is using an IDE like WebStorm, which can create a server for you. This makes your development environment much more like your production environment. Further down the road, take a look at something called Docker.

Comment: I actually have the files on my university's server but I'm just changing some things on my own PC right now. I'll try it out later on, thanks!