# Simple Redirect to another page is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user logs is success in i redirect him to the dashboard.

It used to work ok until i deploy it using tomcat.

now the url is http://localhost:8080/myWar/

so this:

```
 window.location.href = "/dashboard";
```

redirects to http://localhost:8080/dashboard

and I get error 404. How do I redirect this dynamically ?

Comment: Change it to `window.location.href = "./dashboard";` - the dot before the slash makes it relative.  If it starts with a slash it's absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Pathings are usually all the same:

`/` - the "root" Path

`./` - relative from the file's location

so you need to change `window.location.href = "/dashboard";` to `window.location.href = "./dashboard";`

https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

[Difference between Relative path and absolute path in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)

**edit:**

So if your current location is for example `myHost/mypath/subpath` and you'd execute `window.location.href="/myPath"` you'd be redirected to `myHost/myPath` while `window.location.href="./myPath"` redirects you to `myHost/mypath/subpath/myPath`.