# how to call a page with javascript action?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript code on index.php calling a page like this :

```
   id = 5;
   var url = 'pages/pg/'+id+'/';
    f.action  = urlss.toLowerCase();
   return true;
```

the problem is that when I am landing at that page and want to call again with a different ID id doesn't work , I must provide var url the entire path :

```
var url = 'mysite.com/pages/pg/'+id+'/';
```

is there a way to call it without http domaine ?

Comment: It looks like you'll want to use `window.location(url)` for this.

Comment: Yes B3none , It worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative url say (i figure out) from your website root (/).

When you navigate to `pages/pg/<id>` you are in fact navigating to `/pages/pg/<id>`. That is: `<id>` page in `/pages/pg` web directory so your new current path is `/pages/pg` and hence navigating to `pages/pg/<id>` you are in fact navigating to `/pages/pg/pages/pg/<id>` (see url field of your browser...).

Whenever possible I **strongly** advice you to always use absolute url's if you can.

Otherwise you should take care of any path change to properly fix your relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `window.location` property

You can set the absolute url:
`window.location="http://www.google.es"`

The relative path to the current url viewed:
`window.location="./relativePath"`

Or the relative path to the current domain:
`window.location="/domainRelative"`

This another answer explains the absolute vs relative paths
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21306605/4635829