# Send POST request from js file to php file

Tags: javascript, php, email

I created simple html page and I want to send email via php file
and this is my js code for it

```
$.ajax({
    url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
   type: "POST",
    data: {
      name: name,
     phone: phone,
     email: email,
     message: message
   },
```

But when I try to send this request I got 404 NOT FOUND response in my browser.
Is anyone have idea why it doesn't work? If you need more info about this projekt let my know in comment

In this photo you can find my project structure

[image]

Comment: What do you expect from `././`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `..` which makes the relative path go up a directory? Eg `../../mail/contact_me.php` note if the js script is used in index.html and that is the root path for the site the path could just be `/mail/contact_me.php`

Comment: still doesn't work I changed to ../../mail/contact_me.php and move js to index.html but I still get 404

Comment: Note i just used ../.. as an example you need to use the correct relative path or use an absolute path, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript/21306892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` should just point to the /mail subdirectory.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/mail/contact_me.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        message: message
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I also tried this. Also moved php file into js folder and its still give 404 code

Comment: What about url: "/mail/contact_me.php"? Just don't move the .php file. Keep it where it was when you posted the project photo.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full URL for the `contact_me.php` (ie: //example.com/contact_me.php). Relative paths are not going to work from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
url: "../mail/contact_me.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
       name: name,
       phone: phone,
       email: email,
       message: message
      },
 });
```