# Python shell csv problem FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'iris.csv'

Tags: python, shell, csv, csvreader

```py
iris_df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    iris_df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
  File "C:\Python 3.8.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 610, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python 3.8.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 462, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python 3.8.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python 3.8.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1050, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Python 3.8.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1867, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "C:\Python 3.8.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1362, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Python 3.8.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 642, in get_handle
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'iris.csv'
```

What should i do? I imported pandas as pd but it gives me error.Please help

Comment: is your file in the directory?

Comment: how can i check this?

Comment: `import os os.path.exists("iris.csv")`

Comment: The error is very obvious there is no `iris.csv` in the working directory. Would you need some direction on learning more basic of Python? Working Directory?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you don't have the file in the exact folder as your code file. Try keeping them both in the same folder and try this:

```
import pandas as pd
iris_df = pd.read_csv('./iris.csv')
```

Or you can also try copying the exact path to your iris.csv file and then load it using:

```
iris_df = pd.read_csv(' #path to your iris.csv  file')
```

For relative path the `./iris.csv` tells the function to look in the same folder as that of the code file for the iris.csv file. This however won't work if your iris.csv file is in another folder.
In that case:
If you are on a Linux based system your exact path would be something like:

```
home/usr/Desktop/FolderName/iris.csv
```

For a Windows system the absolute path would be something like:

```
C:/Desktop/FolderName/iris.csv
```

Comment: Maybe some additional explaination about absolute path & relative path would help a lot :)

Comment: Yeah sure, this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27938910/13201464) should make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write these two lines of code at the top of your file:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This will change your working directory to the correct path, whatever it was initially.