# Resources path issue (Spring App deployed on Tomcat Server)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, resources

Initially, I deployed my Spring Boot project using the embedded Tomcat Server.
The URL was the following one: `http://localhost:8080/home`.

I have finally used an external Tomcat Server and when I deployed my Spring project the final URL was the following one: `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/home`.

Due to that all my resources paths are modified.

For example:

CSS (located in `src/main/resources/static/css/*`)

```
   Before :  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
```

The only solution that I found is to modify the path to :

```
   After : <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/css/login.css">
```

This is not very maintainable and I would like to know if there is a better solution?

Comment: You could change the root context for external Tomcat to `/` or change root context for embedded Tomcat to `/MyApp`.

Comment: If you change to `href="css/login.css"` without the "/" ?

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Pleft effectively, when I removed the "/" the path is correctly interpreted as : `href="/MyApp/css/login.css"`

Comment: As a general rule you should either use relative URI paths as pleft suggested or prepend the context path to all URIs in your template (e.g. `${contextPath}` in JSPs).

Comment: As @pleft said you should use related path. Also you can read [difference between relative path and absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)

Comment: I adapted the code from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">` to`<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/login.css}">`. It's a mistake from my side because i'm using thymeleaf for my pages