# Email Flexdashboard

Tags: html, flexdashboard

I am trying to email flexdashboard to a colleague.  However, after I knit and try to send an html file, the html page still references my directory. Example - file:///Users/anononymous/Desktop/R/Mens-Traiing/Training_Dashboard_2.html.

Whenever I email this to a colleague clearly they cannot open this file.

I would like to be able to send this to a colleague so that they can open this on their end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative path instead of absolute path in your HTML file.
check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry I am a beginner. I changed my script to use the here package. After looking into your post I saw that this used relative paths. However, I still encounter the same issue?

Comment: without looking at the full source code its difficult to get you a solution. Please post your HTML file..