# Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property while requesting to post method

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "status" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
POST /admin/admin/add-product 404 73.002 ms - 3340

I tried submiting a form to collect data in admin page but the res.post is not working ,The browser shows 'not found' and the above error message is from the console,I'm a begginner and not sure what is causing the error but the nodemon still continues to run,

here is the admin file where the res.post is declared

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let products=[{
    name:"Iphone 15"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by apple"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcR199XXubeTzwSceNjVSDZLSmAS9XKBkftsUbcSGADAGYXqqDRs17BYcd3jocTU_xeenejYWbzJbs394WBFqKBZOwJJcI3il9Pmcz8d3bA&usqp=CAE"
  
  },{
    name:"Samsung Galaxy S23 ultra"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by Samsung"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3uCOtqrOC3OSc1mveQKwrFN4bBVPsOk5FhSznuH-9bZMOU4qHs_-FYJscJ8nFGLDDZ3a_Cla-HCiHjkik3CaBRgsarJ-ZDKErAyLMLe2VRNBIeU1sti7Q&usqp=CAE"
  
  
  },{
    name:"Nothing phone 2"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by NOthing"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvcN7cV_G4iXn6uy8_RoByjPj35Vh1MA0nDKFdg6YNep0EzLTbTsV40YqO1tKxxjFQl8DFOfDW1-vOFTEikA_ZdlrWh9WDwHeFIln0xDuuy2BQRp2wcl4ZTw&usqp=CAE"
  
  },{
    name:"MI 13 ultra"
    ,category:"Mobile"
    ,discription:"flaghship phone by apple"
    ,image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcTv3moXySHfJ_y7ZuoC7S2gxrA2wWtvOe9Zw-YQiwX59uIBkR4IlZuptO9ThOnFiUGLSwpQjcOI8m0LCY19RMWJBcEn66jj_TioDlxIKCJgIekD60awjBYLIg&usqp=CAE"
  
  }]

  res.render('admin/view-products',{admin:true,products})
});
router.get('/add-product',function(req,res){

  res.render('admin/add-product',)
})

router.post('/add-product',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
})

module.exports = router;
```

app.js file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars')
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
var fileUpload=require('express-fileupload')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs',hbs.engine({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname+'/views/layout/',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}))

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', usersRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use(fileUpload())

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

here is html file

```
    <section>
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6" >
                    <h2 class="text-center">Add Product</h2>
                    <form action="admin/add-product"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <label for="">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control">

                        <label for="">Catagory</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Catagory" class="form-control">
                        
                        <label for="">Price</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Price" class="form-control">

                        <label for="">Discription</label>
                        <input type="text " name="Discription" class="form-control">

                        <label for="">Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="Image" class="form-control">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

i want the data collected from the form to be rendered in the console

Comment: add a slash at the beginning of your form's action `<form action="admin/add-product"` --> `<form action="/admin/add-product"` - since it's a RELATIVE path, when you submit a form residing on a page with path `/admin/page.html`, the action will point to `/admin/admin/add-product` - which gives 404

Comment: thakh you it's working

Comment: glad it works, I'm flagging this as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Relative path and absolute path in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)

Comment: but the data is not printing in the console can you help me with that, i mean the data which is been collected from form , using a post method which is there in the code

Comment: your code tries to access `req.body`, are you using body-parser? https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: no iam not using it , i can only see empty braces "{}
POST /admin/add-product - - ms - -"

Comment: use body-parser